# what is autoTableHtmlToJson and where is converting html page?

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

What is `autoTableHtmlToJson`? I do not understand. Also how occurs 'columns' and 'data' ?
Where is html page?

```
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(this.dataGrid.table.nativeElement);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    startY: 20,
    columnStyles: { text: { columnWidth: 'auto' } }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs and examples to see how you can use the latest version of the plugin. In the latest version you can use the `html` option instead of `autoTableHtmlToJson`.

```
doc.autoTable({
    html: this.dataGrid.table.nativeElement
})`
```

In a previous version of autoTable `autoTableHtmlToJson` was used instead of the `html` option to convert an html table to javascript objects that could be passed to the plugin.